# lstlisting error with square bracket

Tags: listings, brackets

Why square bracket does not appear in green in the second example ?

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}  

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\newcommand{\CodeSymbol}[1]{\textcolor{darkgreen}{#1}}

\lstset{
  language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
  }

 \lstdefinestyle{myLangStyleA}{
    literate={\{}{{\CodeSymbol{\{}}}1
}

\lstdefinestyle{myLangStyleB}{
    literate={\{}{{\CodeSymbol{\{}}}1
          {\[}{{\CodeSymbol{\[}}}1, 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myLangStyleA]
[ {
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myLangStyleB]
[ {
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this result :

[image: Green square bracket does not appear]

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bracket `[` is not a special character, so you should simply use it as is.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}  

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\newcommand{\CodeSymbol}[1]{\textcolor{darkgreen}{#1}}

\lstset{
  language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
}

\lstdefinestyle{myLangStyleA}{
  literate={\{}{{\CodeSymbol{\{}}}1
}

\lstdefinestyle{myLangStyleB}{
  literate={\{}{{\CodeSymbol{\{}}}1
           {[}{{\CodeSymbol{[}}}1, 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myLangStyleA]
[ {
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myLangStyleB]
[ {
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]